# adding methods to instance objects

Tags: ruby, methods, instance

Hi guys I have a question on adding methods to instance objects. There is something I don't get.

I'm trying to do a binary search tree in Ruby.
So I made a node class like such:

```
class Node
    attr_accessor :value, :right, :left

    def initialize(value)
        @value = value  
    end
end
```

So when I want to create an instance object from that class I do this:

```
tree = Node.new(10)
```

But if I want to create a binary search tree I need left and right pointers for values that are less and higher than my root number.

So that should go something like this.

```
tree.left = Node.new(8)
tree.right = Node.new(13)
```

And if I want to go further I do this:

```
tree.left.left = Node.new(7)
```

And from my inspect method that I've adapted i get this:

```
"{10::{8::{6::nil|nil}|nil}|nil}"
```

But from this:

```
left=Node.new(1).left = Node.new(2).left = Node.new(3)
```

I get:

```
{3::nil|nil}
```

So, why doesn't this method chaining work like on the previous example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`tap` will help in your case:

```
left = Node.new(1).tap do |n|
  n.left = Node.new(2).tap do |n|
    n.left = Node.new(3)
  end
end
```

Nice article about how you can use the [`tap`](http://seejohncode.com/2012/01/02/ruby-tap-that/) method.

Give it a shot, and let know if it worked!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In ruby the value of assigning something to a variable is the value you are assigning. Which means that if you do

```
a = 5
```

The value of that expression is 5. Moreover, assignments are done right to left. Which means that in your code:

```
left=Node.new(1).left = Node.new(2).left = Node.new(3)
```

You first create `Node.new(3)` and then create Node.new(2) and assign the `Node.new(3)` to `left` of the `2 node`. The result of this assignment is `Node 3` which you assign to `left` of `Node 1`. Again the result of this assignment is `Node 3` which you again assign to your variable `left`. So in the end it acts as if you just assigned `Node 3` to `left`, but doing 2 unnecessary object instantiations on the way.

Comment: tnx for the answer, but how does this work then:  tree.left.left = Node.new(7)  //// "{10::{8::{6::nil|nil}|nil}|nil}"

Comment: In that case you first set tree = Node10, then tree.left = Node8.

Then if you do 
    
    tree.left.left = Node.new(7)

is the same as if you did

    a = tree.left # => Node 8
    a.left = Node.new(7) # Which means you set Node 7 to left of Node 8

This is different than 

    left=Node.new(1).left = Node.new(2).left = Node.new(3)

Comment: tnx for you answer Piotr, so your saying that this would work left=Node.new(1).left = Node.new(2).left = Node.new(3) - If i did it on an instance object like tree = Node.new(10) like the following, tree.left=Node.new(1).left = Node.new(2).left = Node.new(3) - But how is it that I can append the same instance method .left with different new objects with different values in a row but I can't do it without an instance object like tree? Tnx Tom